# How to find gain parameter of complementary filter algorithm for application in navigation

Tags: sensor, accelerometer, physics, imu, gyro

I am using mpu-6050 6 axis Inertial measurement Unit for navigational purpose for tracking orientation and position of a vehicle w.r.t starting point, I am trying to improve the orientation tracking using complementary filter, from what I have understood

I need to apply High pass filter on Gyroscope and Low pass filter on Accelerometer readings.
After this,

I need to apply complementary filter algorithm on these readings,
Since my system is dynamic i.e the car is moving I am unable to find the gain parameter for complementary filter algorithm

where,

angle(complementary) = alpha * (angle from accelerometer after low pass) + (1-alpha) * (angle from gyroscope after high pass)

Any reference/ literature would be helpfull.

Thanks !!